# up/down signals by bars

Tags: wi-fi

I purchased an outside antenna for boosting reception as I live in a mostly dead cell zone now I get up/down/arrows from time to time by my reception bars.  Does this mean my antenna is actually working///

Comment: It just means that something is trying to transfer data. Whethr your antenna works you should see by the numbers of bars.

Answer (score 0):

It means data is being transferred to and from your device. That doesn't necessarily mean it is working.

You should try to use a speedtest app with and without the antenna to see if there is a difference in connection